# java I/O : why don't input and output streams have to match?

Tags: java, sockets, file-io

i am trying to build a client-server java application. Using numerous sample programs online, i noticed everyone has their own variations as to which stream to use and what stream to wrap it in.

However, my main question is, i was wondering why the input stream and the output streams don't have to match as displayed in the following sample code:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
```

for example, shouldn't the outputStream be wrapped in BufferedWriter()?

Comment: If you want the stream to read characters (instead of bytes) you wrap in a writer, and if you want that + buffering you use a BufferedWriter... it all depends on what you application wants to do with the data. Read the javadocs for the related classes. The client and server need to agree on what the data is (a.k.a. the protocol), not how to read / write the data.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to match because each stream stands on its own (despite being associated with the same `Socket` instance).  The Java API wouldn't be very sane if handling a stream one way caused side-effects that required you handle a second, completely independent stream in a certain way.

Nothing prevents you from using a comparable approach to handle both your input and your output streams.  But nothing requires it, either.  In general you should think more about the behavior that you want (and about what *makes sense* for whatever communication protocol you are implementing) than about whether or not the "same" classes are being used to manage input and output.

For instance, you use a `BufferedReader` if you want to read text data line by line.  It would not be appropriate to use this class if you are reading binary data in which newline characters have no special significance.

And similarly, if you want to output text data, it's reasonable to use a `BufferedWriter` to do so.  But you wouldn't generally do that if you need to output binary data.

So really it depends upon what best suits your needs/use-case.  Sometimes your input and output requirement will be the same.  And sometimes not.  The developer's job is to understand the requirements, and use the most appropriate tools to solve the problem.

Comment: numerous sample code online buffers the input but doesn't buffer the output (as shown in the above sample code). Why is this?

Comment: Could be any number of things.  Perhaps it's valid in the context of the example (i.e. they are reading text and writing binary data).  Perhaps they're hastily written examples, or perhaps well-written ones that are trying to show two techniques at once.  In general, you can get a better understanding of things by reading [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) then by reading random snippets of code.